# LuaLaTeX and hyphenation / left/right hyphenmin

Tags: luatex, hyphenation

This is my code (run with LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\lefthyphenmin0
\righthyphenmin0
\hsize 5cm
Also schön, Guido Heffels, nachfolgend meine Textempfehlung für das Blindtextbuch. Sie mögen denken, aus welchem Anlass es unbedingt eine solche poesiealbumhafte Antiquität sein muss, und genau das sollen Sie ja auch. Wenn Sie den Text lange genug mit Fleiß bestaunen, können Sie die Nuss knacken. Denn wenn mein Gag auch nicht mit schnellem Auge zu entdecken ist - eine geduldige Seele muss die Lösung doch finden. Wenn Sie es geschafft haben, dann klingeln Sie mich doch bitte noch einmal an, denn ich muss Ihnen dann noch die Headline zum Text nachsenden.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: no hyphenation in the text]

Questions:

1. setting lefthyphenmin and / or righthyphenmin to 0 turns off hyphenation. PDFTeX does not turn off hyphenation. Why?
2. Setting lefthyphenmin and righthyphenmin to 1 gives me very strange hyphenation results such as 'den-n' or 'mus-s'. Why? Are the hyphenation patterns incorrect? **self answer:** They work as intended. The German hyphenation patterns are to be used with lefthyphenmin and righthyphenmin > 1.

`\begin{edit}`
3) How can I find out which hyphenation pattern file is used for hyphenation?
`\end{edit}`

What am I doing wrong?

(TL 2020)

Comment: As to 3, add the package option `showlanguages` and look at the log file.

Comment: @JavierBezos thank you, that is helpful!

Comment: while it looks odd that it suppresses hyphenation, why do you want to set the hyphenmin to 0?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer To understand TeX (long time to go....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to question 1 and 2 are “works as intended”. The minimum value for `\lefthyphenmin` and `\righthyphenmin` in LuaTeX is 1. The minimum value for `\lefthyphenmin` and `\righthyphenmin` for the German hyphenation patterns is 2.

The third answer has been given by Javier Bezos.

Answer (score 0):

Put `\lefthyphenmin2` or bigger and `\righthyphenmin3` or bigger. If you use `babel` hypenmins will be set automatically by the language you select.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\begin{document}
\hsize 5cm
Also schön, Guido Heffels, nachfolgend meine Textempfehlung für das Blindtextbuch. Sie mögen denken, aus welchem Anlass es unbedingt eine solche poesiealbumhafte Antiquität sein muss, und genau das sollen Sie ja auch. Wenn Sie den Text lange genug mit Fleiß bestaunen, können Sie die Nuss knacken. Denn wenn mein Gag auch nicht mit schnellem Auge zu entdecken ist - eine geduldige Seele muss die Lösung doch finden. Wenn Sie es geschafft haben, dann klingeln Sie mich doch bitte noch einmal an, denn ich muss Ihnen dann noch die Headline zum Text nachsenden.
\end{document}
```

If other languages wanted replace `[ngerman]`  with `[british, main=ngerman]` if you want for example english.

Comment: Thanks Oni for your reply. I am not sure how it answers my questions though. (I have added another sub-question)